# cytoscape.js node unwanted overlap and unexpected styling

Tags: cytoscape.js, arbor.js

I've got a working [cytoscape.js](https://github.com/cytoscape/cytoscape.js) instance that looks like this:
[image: ugly network]

I have been trying unsuccessfully to configure the graph so that the node labels don't overlap.  The graph uses arbor for layout. Playing with the repulsion levels doesn't have much effect on the problem. Gravity (or lack thereof) doesn't either. Is this a layout issue or a cytoscape.js config issue and how do I fix it?

Secondarily, node shape is supposed to be a 40x40 ellipse, which it generally is. But when a node is grabbed, it displays as a rounded rectangle. Why?

I've created a [gist](https://gist.github.com/dnagirl/97f9e803c0c36f69c57d) with my javascript and some data. It's dependent on jQuery (~2.1), cytoscape.js (>=2.3.9) and arbor.js as provided in the cytoscape.js lib directory. And it needs `<div id="cy"></div>` for a target.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

(1) Overlap is a function of layout.  If changing layout parameters is unsuccessful for your usecase, a different layout is probably the solution.

(2) That's the [overlay](http://js.cytoscape.org/#style/overlay) -- not the node's body.

Comment: thanks for the clarification about overlay vs node body. I've set overlay-opacity to zero and no longer see the grey rectangle. Unfortunately, I've not yet found a layout that will display my graph without overlaps.